# MySQL SELECT with IF and QUARTER using UNIX TIME

Tags: mysql, unix-timestamp

I have a date that I'm trying to show as 'Quarters' and I can't make it show anything but `NULL` (or it errors). I want to end up with "2015 Q1" where `endtime` is currently `1422748800` (Feb 1st, 2015).

Here's my current attempt:

```
IF (
    stock.engine = 1, 
    concat(
        YEAR(endtime), ' Q', QUARTER(endtime)
        ) 
    , NULL) as QTR1
```

I've also tried fomatting `endtime` (which is in Unix format) as

```
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(endtime), '%Y')
```

It seems that no matter what I do, this same line keeps throwing an error OR it only shows as `NULL`. How can this be fixed so it shows correctly?

**EDIT:**

I don't know if this is relevant but I'll put it here anyway. The data in the table can have multiples... like so:

```
table: stock
userid      name                        engine     endtime
1           Robert Griffin                 1       1422748800
1           Robert Griffin                 2       1422752615
2           Daryl Jones                    4       1422939585
3           Patrick Daniels                3       1422858023
3           Patrick Daniels                4       1423047328
```

etc.

Comment: In order to give you a "how to fix it", we need to know what's actually wrong. 1)  Are you sure `stock.engine = 1` evaluates to TRUE?  2) What is the *datatype* of the **`endtime`** column, is that defined as a `timestamp`, an `integer` type, a `varchar`?

Comment: To answer your question: everyone has `stock.engine` -- it ranges from 1 to 4. The `endtime` column is formatted as `bigint (10)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `from_unixtime()`.  It looks like you dates are being stored in this format.  So:

```
select (case when stock.engine = 1 
             then concat(year(from_unixtime(endtime)), ' Q', quarter(from_unixtime(endtime))
        end) as QTR1
```

Comment: I see what you did there (with the use of `case`). The only thing I added was `MAX` in front of it and everything turned out beautiful.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are storing `endtime` as an integer, you can use the `FROM_UNIXTIME()` function to convert that to a `datetime`, and then use MySQL builtin functions on the `datetime` value.

As a demonstration:

```
SELECT CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(1422748800),'%Y Q'),QUARTER(FROM_UNIXTIME(1422748800))) AS qtr
```

returns:

```
qtr      
-------
2015 Q1
```

replace the literal integer values with a reference to your (integer) `endtime` column.